# Why am I getting these errors using py2app?

Tags: python, ios, macos, compiler-construction, py2app

Below is what has appeared as an error to me after typing in python setup.py py2app. I'm on a mac. I've spent hours reading tutorials, making sure both py2app and pyapplet were set up, and following the tutorials, I don't know what's wrong. Here's the error:

```
running py2app
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 18, in <module>
    setup_requires=['py2app'],
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/distutils/core.py", line 152, in setup
    dist.run_commands()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/distutils/dist.py", line 975, in run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/distutils/dist.py", line 995, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/py2app-0.7.3-py2.6.egg/py2app/build_app.py", line 502, in run
    if sysconfig.get_config_var('PYTHONFRAMEWORK') is None:
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_config_var'
```

And here is my setup.py

```
"""
This is a setup.py script generated by py2applet

Usage:
    python setup.py py2app
"""

from setuptools import setup

APP = ['kradio.py']
DATA_FILES = []
OPTIONS = {'argv_emulation': True}

setup(
    app=APP,
    data_files=DATA_FILES,
    options={'py2app': OPTIONS},
    setup_requires=['py2app'],
)
```

Both the program and the setup are located in the user directory.

Comment: you have an extra comma `,` in `setup_requires=['py2app'],` that doesn't need to be there

Comment: Changed it, still broken, but thanks

Comment: You tried to create package from some example hello world program?

Comment: Just use pip. >pip install py2app. https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pip

Comment: @sousipse, no, I made a small radio program, and now I want to make it usable by others. sihrc, I'll try that. I'm pulling hair out at this point

Comment: Ok I've used pip to install py2app. Says that requirement is already satisfied and then it cleaned up. Now what?

Comment: Did you figure this out? I am facing the same issue.